# Maven project: Http 404 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, netbeans

Got the following files for a Maven+Spring+Hibernate+MySQL project (under NetBeans):

```
project /
   + Web Pages /
      + WEB-INF /
         + views /
            + login.jsp
         + servlet-context.xml
      + index.jsp
      + web.xml
   + Source /
      + users /
         + User.java
         + UserDAO.java
         + UserController.java
```

This is web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

This is servlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- Enable @Controller annotation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Map simple view name such as "test" into /WEB-INF/test.jsp -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Scan classpath for annotations (eg: @Service, @Repository etc) -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="users"/>

    <!-- JDBC Data Source. It is assumed you have MySQL running on localhost port 3306 with 
    username root and blank password. Change below if it's not the case -->
    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/private"/>
        <property name="username" value="private"/>
        <property name="password" value="private"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate Session Factory -->
    <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <array>
                <value>users</value>
            </array>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Activates annotation based transaction management -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
</beans>
```

And got index.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <% response.sendRedirect("login"); %>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I launch the proyect, over Glassfish server, then it replies:
**HTTP Status 404: Not Found
The requested resource is not available**

URL is "**localhost:8080/private/login**"

UPDATE:
This is the controller:

```
package user;
imports[...]
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView doLogin(HttpServletRequest request){
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        String email = request.getParameter("usermail");
        String password = request.getParameter("userpass");

        List<User> users = userDAO.findUser(email, password);
        if (!users.isEmpty()){
            model.addObject("user", users.get(0));
            model.setViewName("home"); //will be endpoint in case of success
        }else{
            model.addObject("message", "Invalid user email or password!");
            model.setViewName("error"); //will be endpoint for any error
        }

        return model;
    }

}
```

And this is the login.jsp file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
         pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>web</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form:form method="POST" action="login">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label>email:</label>
                    <form:input type="email" id="usermail" path="usermail"/>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>password:</label>
                    <form:input type="password" id="userpass" path="userpass"/>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you have in controller mappings?

Comment: See **UPDATE** (above)

Comment: I don't see anything which would map to GET for /private/login